# What is the official name for these jumper wires?

Tags: prototyping

What is the official name for the kind of prototyping wires seen at [this link](http://www.adafruit.com/products/758)?

[image]

I noticed that on [this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55053/does-something-like-a-reverse-jumper-wire-exist) the above kind of wire (with the "square" end) was referred to as a "jumper wire".  Some other sources refer to the ones with a "round" end as either a *jumper wire* or a *breadboard wire*.

To make matters more confusing, the Wikipedia entry for [Breadboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadboard#Jump_wires) refers to the "round end" type as "jumper wire".

When buying these wires off some websites from Taiwan, I noticed that the sellers will sometimes refer to them as "杜邦頭跳線" (*Dupont Header jumper wires*).  Googling for "Dupont header" does indeed show me the kind of pin header suited for the wire in question.

So is that its real name?  A *Dupont Header* jumper wire?

Comment: Male to Male?  You could also consider the greatest distance between two points as the diameter and call it gauge.

Comment: The point wasn't whether it was M-M, F-F, or M-F, but rather, what the official name for the 'square end' wires is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dupont is a manufacturer of plastic products, much like Tyvek or Molex. The name has become synonymous with 0.1" 2.57mm headers, especially with jumper cables like these. As far as I can tell Dupont doesn't make these headers themselves.

This is similar to Molex being used to refer to computer 4 pin power connectors used for 3.5" drives, just because Molex does manufacturer them.

The ***real*** name of any part is whatever the community has de facto decided to call them. The real technical name is 0.1" Square Header on 22 awg Breakaway Ribbon Cable (with male to male or male to female or female to female or whatever as appropriate).

Comment: Thankyou so much for your knowledgeable answer!  I'm off to the shop to buy some "0.1" Square Header on 22 awg Breakaway Ribbon Cable" :).

Comment: When you go to the shop, it might be wise to take a sample jumper with you, so you can ask "do you have anything like this?"

Answer (score 2):

On EBAY, it is "40-wire male to male Dupont Ribbon Cable" or some variation of these words.  For better hits on EBAY, search for "DuPont Ribbon Male -Female", where the "-female" excludes all matches with the word female, otherwise it would include male-to-female and female-to-female cables.